# What is this bike model and year? Cannondale CAAD?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have an opportunity to buy this bike for $200 and was wondering what model and year the bike is? From one of the pictures I see CAAD and on another, I see seven, but I'm coming up empty handed when googling. The owner says he bought it last year.

Thanks!
Mike
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Cannondale Quick 7: https://www.cannondale.com/en/USA/Bike/ProductDetail?Id=7adbe241-cc33-4ea5-b62f-9f32c8476f31

Not sure of the year; you can look up previous years and see if the color scheme is different, or if the components match what was spec'd on that year (derailleur, shifters, number of gears, etc.).

It's a fairly entry level hybrid from a major company, so bikes like these don't go huge overhauls very often -- it doesn't look much different than the 2018 visually aside from the black crankset in the figure below.

Image from Cannondale.com

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought too but the crank on this is silver whereas on the photo is black. Maybe it was swapped out

Comment: It could also just be black in your market, or cannondale didn't update the photo from last year; a lot of ones that come up as 2018's on google image search have black cranksets.